# extract the date from ID and get the data for last one year

Tags: sql, oracle, date, extract, records

I have below query in which i can extract the date using `to_date(substr(id, 1, 14), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')` from id column. But now i want to get the data for last one year comparins this date from id column.

```
select count(*) as cnt from in_test where id > 201200000000000000 and status not in (0,1)
```

Comment: You want the last full calendar year (January to December), or the last 365 days?

Comment: i want last 365 days means i should get the record from 31.08.2015 till now

Comment: What is the data type of `id`? Number?

Comment: yes its number data type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the data that is equal or later than today, one year ago, then:

```
where  id >= to_number(to_char(add_months(sysdate,-12), 'YYYYMMDD'))*10000000000
```

This assumes that you have given the correct number of digits in your question. Otherwise you may need to append/remove some zeroes from that final number.

For today, the expression on the right results in this number:

```
201508310000000000
```

#### Explanation

`sysdate` is the Oracle way to get the current time stamp as a `datetime`.

`add_months(...,-1)` subtracts 1 year from that date, so if we do this today (31 August 2016), we get `201510831`.

`to_char(..., 'YYYYMMDD')` converts that datetime to a string, in the format `YYYYMMDD`. So that will result in the string `20150831`.

`to_number(...)` converts that string to numeric data type, i.e. to `20150831`.

`*10000000000` multiplies that number so that it gets the same range like your `id` range seems to be, which gives the final result `201508310000000000`.

Comment: can you please explian the logic why we have multiplies 1000000000?

Comment: Sure, I added it to my answer.

Comment: is not possbile using add_months ? because the first 20160831 gives proper YYYYMMDD and we can simply comapre with this and get the data from last one year ? So it will avoids digits issue .

Comment: Of course, I completely forgot to subtract 1 year! I updated the answer.

Comment: @Andrew - Yes, it is possible. Iinstead of `sysdate` use `add_months(sysdate, -12)`. Otherwise you should use trincot's approach, if your base table has many rows and the id is in number format, especially if you have an index on it (and if you don't you should). Applying all the transformations to `sysdate` and nothing to `id` will allow the query engine to use the index, resulting in much, much faster performance.

Comment: @trincot - this may be splitting hairs - I wonder if concatenating the '000...0' while the date was cast as string, and only then casting to number, would be faster than multiplying by 1000...0 ?

Comment: @mathguy, maybe... I suppose it will not differ much in performance in either way. To be tested :)